# css incorrect after change of command name

Tags: css

Big project, semi-competent programmer, much confusion.
Example: I wrote the CSS command that sets the formatting for the book's title

```
h0 { text-align: center; ... }
```

and it worked. Time passed, I made changes -- one of which disrupted the entire CSS enterprise. During repair, I began to wonder if 'h0' was in some way a forbidden name, so changed it to

```
h1 { text-align: center; ... }
```

and moved it out of a CSS file to the 'style' section of 'ChapTab.shtml', the first HTML loaded and  the only place it is used. This works.

But I have used 'h1' for another format many places later on, so I change this command back to

```
h0 { text-align: center; ... }
```

and it puts the title at the left.

FF's CSS-usage add-on shows this 'h0' (as written) as the active command, but disobeyed. I find this confusing unless 'h0' is indeed pre-empted, or something. What's going on?

You can see this happening at the title of the page
http://www.electromontis.net/evoligion/_A/A00.shtml 

 (We will worry about the oversize font in the left column of the table, and the perpetual left-alignment below, at some later date.)

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no such thing as h0 (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp). So you might either try to change it to an h1 or make it a <div> with a classname.

Comment: @Rubenxfd is correct - also, although you're setting `text-align: center` your element is left aligned, and it has no width set so this will have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

`h0` is being treated as an inline element, so the `text-align` property won't work on it. Add the property `display: block`; to `h0` to make it a block element. The `text-align` property works on block elements.

And I agree with @Rubenxfd - I'm not aware of an `h0` tag. Best to stick with HTML standard tags where there are default properties (like `display`).

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no `h0` tag, so browser renders it as `<span>`. Add `h0 {display: block}` to act as `h1` tag.
2. Your `th` has `font-size: 140%;`. Change/remove it.
3. `perpetual left-alignment below` Did not get this one, but if you are talking about all elements that are left-aligned below table: There is no align rules set, so it's left-aligned by default.